# Не импортируется БД MySQL в Visual Studio 2017

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

- сервер localhost (Denwer)
- MySQL 5.6.26
- MySQL connector net 6.10.5
- MySQL for visualstudio 1.2.7

Старые проекты, созданные под Visual Studio 2012 работают.
Сервер localhost подключается.

Но при импорте структуры данных из источника данных *MySQL Database (MySQL Data Provider) (.NET Framework Data Provider for MySQL*) ошибка:

> Не удалось создать автоматически некоторые команды обновления. База данных вернула следующую ошибку: Непредвиденная ошибка.

При этом структура DataSet создается с именами таблиц базы данных, но сами таблицы без полей. Подскажите в чем проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Отвечаю сам: 
проблемы с **MySQL connector net** - работает только версия **6.9.8**